# Why does this second loop have no initialization? And why does it print five stars?

Tags: c, for-loop

This program produces this output:

```
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
```

Here's the code:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
 int i, j;
 for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
 {
  for (j = 1; j < i;j++)
   printf(" ");
  for (; j <= 8 - i;j++)
   printf("*");
  printf("\n");
 }
 return 0;
}
```

What's the meaning of `for (; j <= 8 - i;j++)`? There is no initialization step and also don't understand why there is only five * on the second line.

Comment: The j variable already has a value so you don't need to initialize it... And it's not java.

Comment: to figure out the number of stars, step through the debugger and watch `j`

Comment: oops.. you guys are right.. this is C, not java.. my mistake!

Answer (score 4):

For loops don't actually need to have an initialization statement. Many loops choose to include one, but it's not strictly necessary. Consequently, you can think of that loop as saying "we don't need to do anything special here for initialization."

As for why there are five stars on the second line, let's look at this part of the code:

```
for (j = 1; j < i;j++)
 printf(" ");
for (; j <= 8 - i;j++)
 printf("*");
```

On the second iteration, `i` is equal to 2. When the first loop runs, it will print out a single space character. The loop stops running when `j < i` is no longer true, so when it finishes running, the value of `j` will be 2. Therefore, the second loop will run for `j =`2, 3, 4, 5, 6, stopping when `j = 7`. That's why you see five stars.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah... so you are saying that since there is no initialization of the second loop the j is 2 and the second loop begins with j = 2!!!!! It took a while to figure out this part.. thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1):

> What's the meaning of for (; j <= 8 - i;j++)?

That for takes the last (known) value of j used in the program

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (; j <= 8 - i;j++)
 printf("*");
```

Here there is no need for initialization of `j` as value of `j` comes from previous for loop.

First case `i=1` and `j=1` but condition in loop is false and `j` increments to `2`. And this value goes in innermost loop which runs till `j=7`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, j is initialized in the outer most block with respect to the for loops so now j is accessible from all the for loop (or any other loop).

it uses the last modified(incremented) value by the outermost for loop.

i think you can figure it now .

just figure out it by using copy pen and create a matrix for the for loop variables.

it will surely improve your programming skills.

Happy Coding.

you can try this:

[variations in for loop in C](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-for-loop-types/#Different_Ways_of_Using_For_Loop_in_C_Programming)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The variable i and j are available outside of for loop! You're absolutely right!

Answer (score 0):

That loop is using the `j` variable from the for loop directly above it. Each iteration of it is shorter by 2; one from the beginning, and one from the end. That is how it maintains the text centrally on the screen.

So, the first iteration at `i=1` will not print any `" "`. It will then print 7 `*`, from `j` values of 1-7.

The second iteration at `i=2` will print one `" "`, followed by 5 *, from `j` values of 2-6.

Each iteration subsequently follows this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include  <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
 int i, j;
 for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) **1**
 {
  for (j = 1; j < i;j++) **2**
   printf(" ");
  for (; j <= 8 - i;j++) **3**
   printf("*");
  printf("\n");
 }
 return 0;
}
```

You will find that the variable j does not need to be initialized in loop 3 as it has been initialized in loop 2, and it is within the scope of the local block (j exists within loop 1, and need'nt to be initialised after loop 2).

With regard to your second query, 
    consider the second iteration of loop1 where i=2. When loop2 completes its execution at this point, j=2. Now consider loop3, where j is 2 (as previously established) and it executes until j is less than or equal to 8-i(8-i=8-2= 6).
So it prints a star for j = 2,3,4,5,6 = 5 stars.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
printf("*");
```

by

```
printf("%d", j)
```

and look how the value of j is changing. This could explain how it works.